# Problem installing a ruby gem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, gcc, ruby, gem

I have a problem installing a Rubygem `pdfbeads` on my Ubuntu 16.04 and wonder if anyone could help.

I never used or ran `ruby` before, but I needed this gem as it is required within a DJVU-to-PDF file converter script `djvu2pdf.sh` I'd like to use (if interested, see [Converting DJVU to PDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46233/converting-djvu-to-pdf) on Ask Ubuntu).

Installing the `pdfbeads` current version 1.1.1 proved far from trivial. First, it required the installation of a newer version of `ruby` than the default version 2.3 available through `apt` on Ubuntu. So, to install the latest version `ruby 2.7` I had to use `snap` instead. Next, the dependency gem `rmagick` was missing and had to be installed. That failed since it requires a newer C compiler version `gcc-8` rather than the current Ubuntu default `gcc-5`. To be on the safe side, I installed multiple versions `gcc-6`, `gcc-7`, `gcc-8` and `gcc-9` allowing me to select the system default version by running `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`. After all that, using the `gcc-8 (v.8.3.0)`, I was able to successfully install the gem by running `gem instal pdfbeads`. Finally, I was ready to run the `djvu2pdf.sh` script.

However, running the script produces the following error in its last step:

```bsh
Building the final pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from ~/.gem/bin/pdfbeads:23:in '<main>'
    3: from ~/.gem/bin/pdfbeads:23:in 'load'
    2: from ~/.gem/gems/pdfbeads-1.1.1/bin/pdfbeads:35:in '<top (required)>'
    1: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in 'require'
/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in 'require': 
cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
```

Line 35 in `pdfbeads` requires `iconv` and `ruby` can't find it. Normally `ruby` tries to load it from the existing `ruby LOAD_PATH`, and when it fails, it searches the installed gems. Apparently, `iconv` was not installed in any of the previous steps. Gem `iconv` is a wrapper class for the UNIX 95 `iconv()` function family, which translates string between various encoding systems. Note, however, that `iconv` is not listed as a `pdfbeads 1.1.1` dependency on its rubygem.org [dependencies page](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdfbeads/versions/1.1.1/dependencies). Also note that unpacking the `pdfbeads 1.1.1` gem reveals that it was not created using the `ruby bundler` as it contains no `Gemfile`. Therefore, modifying the script to run `pdfbeads` with `bundle-exec` is of no help.

Here's where I run into the problem I can't solve. When I try installing the missing `iconv` gem with `gem install iconv` I get numerous C compiler error messages too long to list here. I tried running this with each different version of `gcc` - 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 and none of them succeeds. With version `gcc 6.5.0` I got only one error message - `make` fails after this error:

```bsh
$ cat mkmf.log 
"gcc -o conftest -I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward 
-I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I. -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond 
-Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings 
-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long 
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality 
-Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format 
-Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/snap/ruby/172/lib -Wl,-rpath,/snap
/ruby/172/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath,/snap/ruby/172/lib 
-L/snap/ruby/172/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0’; did you mean ‘-Wno-fallthrough’?
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */
```

The unrecognized command line option ‘-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0’ is set within the configuration file `/snap/ruby/169/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb` which lies on a `snap` disk partition which is mounted read-only:

```bsh
$ grep "[[:space:]]ro[[:space:],]" /proc/mounts | grep ruby
/dev/loop15 /snap/ruby/170 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop33 /snap/ruby/169 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

With version `gcc 8.3.0`, this first `gcc` invocation does not cause any error, however the next one does::

```bsh
"gcc -o conftest -I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward 
-I/snap/ruby/172/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond 
-Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings 
-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long 
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality 
-Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format 
-Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable -fPIC conftest.c -L. -L/snap/ruby/172/lib -Wl,-rpath,/snap/ruby/172/lib -L. 
-fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath,/snap/ruby/172/lib -L/snap/ruby/172/lib -lruby -lm -lc"
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: undefined reference to '__open_nocancel@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/snap/ruby/172/lib/libruby.so: undefined reference to 'getrandom@GLIBC_2.25'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '_IO_enable_locks@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__mmap@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__munmap@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_catch_error@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__mprotect@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: undefined reference to '__snprintf@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__tunable_get_val@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: undefined reference to '__read_nocancel@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__close_nocancel@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/snap/ruby/172/lib/libruby.so: undefined reference to 'copy_file_range@GLIBC_2.27'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__sigtimedwait@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_signal_error@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/snap/ruby/172/lib/libruby.so: undefined reference to '__explicit_bzero_chk@GLIBC_2.25'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <ruby/encoding.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_enc_get; return !p; }
/* end */
```

followed by a whole bunch of other errors, too long to list.

Next, I tried earlier versions of ruby - 2.6, 2.5, 2.4 - and with `gcc-8` (as required for RMagick 4.0.0 package compilation), last 2 versions produce slightly fewer errors. However, when using `gcc 6.5.0` I get exactly the same error with `ruby 2.4` and as with `ruby 2.7`.

Would anyone have any suggestion how to solve this problem?